# Can I use a Early 2011 MacBook Pro 13" charger with my Late 2013 MacBook Pro 13" with the MagSafe Adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, magsafe

I bought a Early 2011 MacBook Pro 13" but eventually upgraded to a newer Retina Late 2013 13" model.  I'd like to get another charger, but I'm curious if I could use the old charger that came with that laptop with this new one if I buy the [MagSafe to MagSafe 2 adapter](http://store.apple.com/ca/product/MD504LL/A/magsafe-to-magsafe-2-converter?fnode=5a).  They both use a 60W adapter, so I don't see a reason why they shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer-- yes you can! there should be no any problems.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I'll mark this as correct when Stack Exchange lets me.

Comment: Don't worry about that, go now and charge :)